# Java Spring - How to upload a file and then return the response in the html Front-end?

Tags: javascript, java, html, ajax, spring

I want to upload a File in using front-end, to access it via my Controller and check the file with java. The file I want to upload is an XML-File. I check it with an XML-scheme and it works perfectly.

html:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/uploadXML">
    <input name="file" type="file" id="importFile" /> <br>
    <button name="button" type="submit" class="buttonUpload">Upload</button>
</form>
```

in my Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/uploadXML", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String handleFileUpload( 
        @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file){
        String name = "test11";
    if (!file.isEmpty()) {
        try {
            byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
            BufferedOutputStream stream = 
                    new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(name + "-uploaded")));
            stream.write(bytes);
            stream.close();
            File convertedFile = convert(file);



            //Response response = new Response("Done", name);
            //return response;
           return validateAgainstSchema(convertedFile);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Response response = new Response("fail", name);
            //return response;
            return "You failed to upload " + name + " => " + e.getMessage();
        }
    } else {

        //Response response = new Response("fail", name);
        //return response;
        return "You failed to upload " + name + " because the file was empty.";
    }
}
```

Here I get the uploaded file, with `*convert(file)*` I convert the MultiparFile to a "normal" file. With *`validateAgainstSchema`()* I check if the XML-File is in the right format. 
Now to the part I do not understand. From * `validateAgainstSchema`()* I get the String "File is in the right format" or I get "File is not in the right format". If I return this string in my Controller my browser redirects to a new page which only contains this string.

But I just want the result to show in my single-Page-Application in e.g. a  in my Front-End. I figured out that ajax could be a way to solve this problem.

my ajax-code:

```
  $( document ).ready(function() {

    var url = window.location;

    // SUBMIT FORM
    $("#customerForm").submit(function(event) {//hier die 1 entfernen!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        // Prevent the form from submitting via the browser.
        event.preventDefault();
        ajaxPost();
    });


    function ajaxPost(){

        // PREPARE FORM DATA
    /*  var formData = {
            firstname : $("#firstname").val(), //nachher um Textfelder und so auszulesen
            lastname :  $("#lastname").val()
        }*/

        var text = "..........,";

        // DO POST
        $.ajax({
            //type : "POST",
            contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",

            url : url,
            //url : url + "/uploadXml",
            //url:  "/uploadXML",
            data : text,
            //data : JSON.stringify(formData),
            //dataType : 'json',
            success : function(result) {
                //result ist hier mein html document
                if(result.status == "Done"){

                /*  $("#postResultDiv").html("<strong>" + "Post Successfully! Customer's Info: FirstName = " 
                            + result.data.firstname + " ,LastName = " + result.data.lastname + "</strong>"); */

                    $("#postResultDiv").html("<strong>" + "success" + "</strong>");
                }else{
                    $("#postResultDiv").html("<strong>" + "error" + "</strong>");
                }
                console.log(result);
                console.log("test.............");
            },
            error : function(e) {
                alert("Error!")
                console.log("ERROR: ", e);
            }
        });



    }


})
```

This part I don't understand at all. I used a version I found on the web and adjusted it a bit. (I added id="customerForm" to my `input type="file" btw.` ). Now if i press the submit button my div gets the text "error" and nothing more happens, except my html gets printed in the console and my ajax-request prints a "success" in the console. 
The "result" in my ajax code seems to be my html code. Can you please explain to me how i can return the result of the XML-checking-procedure in my div?

And just in the case someone can explain this to me, how do I save the XML File? I need it later in my project.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of div you can use IFRAME to display your result.

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/uploadXML" target="result">
    <input name="file" type="file" id="importFile" /> <br>
    <button name="button" type="submit" class="buttonUpload">Upload</button>
</form>
<iframe id="result" name="result"></iframe>
```